# "he is too young to go to school, is he " or "he is too young to go to school, isn't he?"

Tags: questions, question-tags

Can you tell me which of the following sentences is correct? why?

> **a)** He is too young to go to school, is he?
>
> **b)** He is too young to go to school, isn't he?

Comment: I would use the latter.

Comment: Flora: You might want to check out the relatively new [ell.se].

Answer (score 5):

Both are correct, but there a difference in meaning

The first suggests that you are challenging a statement from someone else  "He is too young to go to school"

The second, that you are seeking confirmation for the initial statement.

Comment: "challenging a statement" -> Do you mean that someone else said "He is too young to go to school" and I repeat the exact same sentence and only add "is he"? Wouldn't it be more natural just to say "Is he?" or "Really?". Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: I think it's the other way around

Comment: @axrwkr You think **what** "is the other way round"? Are you referring to the previous comment, or to the answer, or something else?

Comment: @TrevorD that "He is too young to go to school, isn't he?" is a challenge, but maybe that depends more on intonation

Comment: @axrwkr I think you're reading it the wrong way round. The assertion is that "He is too young to go to school, **is** he?" is the challenge (which I agree with).

Comment: @Em1: Yes, but the statement isn't parroted back – it's said in a different way. For example, if the first person blandly said, "He is too young to go to school," then the challenger would respond with, "Oh, he's too **young** to go to school, **is he**?" with fairly heavy emphasis on where I've bolded the words. It's a variant of, "Oh, you think he's too **young** to go to school – do you?"

Comment: @TreverD - done.

Comment: @J.R. I see. That makes sense. Thanks for clarification. - I think, user46665, it would be nice to make this more obvious in your answer.

Comment: Whilst the challenge to a prior statement is one possibility,  _He's  too young to go to school, is he?_ could also simply be an unmarked question (emphasis would be quite different if spoken). A third possibility is that the speaker is registering surprise at just discovering the fact. _He is too young to go to school, isn't he?_ shows that one is aware that this is probably the case but is just seeking confirmation.